# What is a safe and easy way to exchange data from a threaded ISR? (Raspberry Pi)

Tags: multithreading, raspberry-pi, interrupt, irq, isr

I'm trying to develop a C/C++ userspace application on the Raspberry Pi which processes data coming from an SPI device. I'm using the **[WiringPi](http://wiringpi.com/)** Library (function **[wiringPiISR](http://wiringpi.com/reference/priority-interrupts-and-threads/#post-1640)**) which registers a function (the real interrupt handler) that will be called from a pthreaded interrupt handler on an IRQ event.

**I heard that STL containers aren't thread safe, but is it enough to have a mutex lock while executing my callback function and of course a lock in the main thread while accessing the buffer/container there?**

My "real interrupt handler" which is registered through *wiringPiISR* looks like this

```c
std::deque<uint8_t> buffer;

static void irq_handler()
{
    uint8_t data;
    while (digitalRead(IRQ_PIN)==0)
    {
        data = spi_txrx(CMD_READBYTE);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex1);
        callback(data);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex1);
    }
}

static void callback(uint8_t byte)
{
    buffer.push_back(byte);
}
```

**Or is there an easier way to achieve the data exchange between a threaded ISR and main thread?**

Comment: You cannot take a mutex in an ISR - you just can't!  An ISR cannot wait for a lock.

Comment: so what is your suggestion?

Comment: I think all the ISR thing is polluting the question. Call it handler, as your real question seems to be, is it ok to use STL containers in multithreaded application, provided they are protected by a mutex.

Answer (score 0):

Is that a real ISR ?
Anyway mutex are not a good fit for ISR, because they lead  to priority inversion.
Let's look at normal mutex usage, with two thread :

1. Thread A runs and take the mmutex
2. for some reason, thread A is preempted, and thread B executes.
3. thread B try to take the mutex, but can't.
4. thread B is put to sleep, allowing another thread to run, for instance thread C or thread A
5. ...
6. At some point, thread A wille be rescheduled, will resume it's operation, and release the mutex.
7. When thread B is scheduled again, takes the mutex.

Now the scenario is very different when it comes to ISR. ISR won't be put to sleep in favor of a lower priority thread, so the mutex owning thread will not run while you are in the ISR, and you will never get out of point three.

So the real question is, "When running an IRQ handler, is it possible for other code to run ?" Otherwise you are in deadlock !

Comment: I don't get it why the ISR won't be put to sleep again? I mean yeah the ISR should have a higher priority than then main thread but if it can't take the mutex it will sleep until the main thread will release the lock, won't it? I think this ISR is not like an atomic ISR in a microcontroller. As long as this is a userspace thread of the underlying linux kernel the execution of real kernel ISRs like context switching of threads should still be possible, or am I wrong in that?

Comment: If the ISR can sleep, then there is no problem, but then maybe it should not be named that way.