# Interaction with a thread from ISR using C++ Standard Library on ESP32

Tags: c++, concurrency, interrupt, esp32, arduino-esp32

**How can I create or notify a thread (or similar) from within an ISR function?**

#### Constraints

- Using C++17
- Using the C++ Standard Library ([std](/questions/tagged/std)) implementation (provided by Arduino-ESP32).
- The mechanism must be functioning, when simulating with [Wokwi](https://wokwi.com/).
  This is crucial, as it is the base for testing without hardware.
- But with no further dependencies, if possible.

The software architecture aims to rely on the least possible platform specific dependencies.
Vanilla C++17 and `std` are accepted dependencies.

#### Background

I want to define and use a concurrent running timer whose execution (start/reset) is controlled by the ISR.

I have tried to create a `std::thread` or notify a waiting one with `std::condition_variable`.
Both occasionally lead to deadlocks when the hardware triggers the interrupt.
When the program is executed in Wokwi it happens every time.
Thus I assume the button bouncing (thus ISR call) is more frequent in the simulator.

**[Here](https://wokwi.com/projects/393080090296594433)** is an online simulation of the problem. Push the button to trigger the ISR and observe the backtrace in the serial terminal.

Debugging in VS Code:
[image: screenshot of the call stack in VS Code when program runs into abort]

I assume some (or all) concurrency methods which require some kind of synchronization (lock) are likely to deadlock if used within an ISR?

- I found [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20453149/what-is-a-safe-and-easy-way-to-exchange-data-from-a-threaded-isr-raspberry-pi#comment30559792_20453149) which suggests that one can not use locks within ISRs
- Calling `std` functions [may be a problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66016919/5534993) as I can not know if their code will be copied into RAM (`IRAM_ATTR`)
- If an ISR is called with highest priority and the synchronization mechanism needs to wait for a lock, a deadlock will occur ([is it priority inversion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20453492/5534993)?).

### Summary

How can the interaction with a concurrently running thread (timer) be achieved from within an ISR?

- Is it correct that I can not reliably use synchronization mechanisms from `std` within an ISR for this?
- What are the alternatives (preferably independent of ESP/Espressif or additional dependencies like [using FreeRTOS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20453149/5534993))?

Comment: Note that the Standard Library is not an implementation of STL. Portions of the Standard Library are *inspired by* the STL, often greatly enough that the STL naming can still be found scattered throughout the code. If you really want to use the STL and not the Standard Library, be very clear.

Comment: I don't know  Arduino specifics. In general isr's should be as simple and fast as possible. Do not block in an ISR. Acquiring a mutex is blocking, so is absolutely out. [std::condition_variable is a synchronization primitive used with a std::mutex to block](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) , so forget that. Do not use any library function that you do not know is safe for isr use. . . .

Comment: I've never tried what you are doing, but I generally treat an ISR similarly to how I treat a signal handler: I do the minimum possible work, set a flag, and then get the hell out of the handler. Some other part of the program monitors the flag and does the tricky stuff. Condition variable notify from a signal handler isn't safe, and unless the OS calls it out specifically, I wouldn't expect it to be safe in an ISR.

Comment: mbed, for example, [specifically states this won't work](https://os.mbed.com/docs/mbed-os/v6.16/apis/rtos-apis.html) with it's built-in condition variable and `std::condition_variable` would  almost certainly based on the supplied OS primitive. FreeRTOS may have some ultra-cool mechanism to make this work, but I doubt it.

Comment: . . . Confine the interaction between the isr and the rest of the code to be as minimal as possible. Just do what you must in the ISR. In the other code that is feed from the isr poll for stuff available from the ISR. To poll, mask the interrupt, check/adjust the shared variables copying any data needed to local(not shared with the isr) variables, unmask the interrupt and then do what work you need to with the data you copied out. You might do this in a polling loop in a thread that also uses a sleep give up the CPU to avoid a busy wait. Or you might design your polling some other way.

Comment: If a single value that can be dealt with on your platform with accessible, hardware guaranteed atomic read-modify-write functionality is available and adequate to your use case, then you might be able to skip the mask/unmask in that specific case. That is both design and platform specific.

Comment: Thank you for [pointing out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78208010/interaction-with-a-thread-from-isr-using-c-standard-library-on-esp32#comment137878372_78208010) the inaccuracy of referring to STL instead of C++ Standard Library [@user4581301](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4581301/user4581301). I adjusted my question accordingly.

Comment: @AviBerger, all [your](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78208010/interaction-with-a-thread-from-isr-using-c-standard-library-on-esp32?noredirect=1#comment137878517_78208010) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78208010/interaction-with-a-thread-from-isr-using-c-standard-library-on-esp32?noredirect=1#comment137878614_78208010) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78208010/interaction-with-a-thread-from-isr-using-c-standard-library-on-esp32?noredirect=1#comment137878684_78208010) would make a valuable answer IMHO. You may want to mention `std::atomic_flag` for the second part 